# iTunes purchase charged to credit card instead of voucher

Tags: family-sharing

I recently set up Family sharing.  My son purchased a game from Apple thinking he was using his iTunes voucher but the purchase has gone straight on to my credit card via family sharing.  How can I rectify this?
thanks

Comment: Did he redeem the iTunes gift card and place a credit on his iTunes account first?  If he was expecting to enter the gift card number at time of purchase, that's too late.   The gift card must be redeemed first, creating "store credit" on his iTunes account.

Answer (score 1):

If you've properly setup Family Sharing, then any purchases made by the family should deduct from the iTunes gift card (assuming this is what you mean when you say 'voucher') instead of your credit card.  According to [this Apple product page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201079):

> After you set up your family, any time a family member initiates a new purchase it will be billed directly to your account, unless that family member has gift or store credit. First, their store credit will be used to pay the partial or total bill. The remainder will bill to the family organizer's card. As the family organizer, any receipts generated by the transaction will be sent to you.

If you see that your card is being charged instead of the gift card, contact [Apple iTunes Support](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/).